# Duplicated code in web service consumption

Tags: c#

I have a set of classes that abstract away calls to a set of web services. I have 6 classes in this particular group, 4 of which contain a simple function that, while small, is still duplicated. What happens is that if some exception or business rule violation happens in the service, they package it up as a fault object in the response. Otherwise, the fault object is null. As a result, the functions simply check to see if that object is not null and, if so, take the reason provided and throw an exception up the chain. So in one class, it might look like

```
private void ThrowIfContainsFault(AlphaResponse response)
{
    if (response.Fault != null)
    {
        throw new WhateverException(response.Fault.reasonText);
    }
}
```

And then the other classes, the response object will be of a different type, but the `Fault` property is the same and the block of code is the same.

```
private void ThrowIfContainsFault(BravoResponse response)
private void ThrowIfContainsFault(CharlieResponse response)
private void ThrowIfContainsFault(DeltaResponse response)
```

(**Note**: These class names are changed for readability, there is no common ancestor for these response objects.)

My first thought is that I could simply change the functions to receive the `Fault` object directly and forget the response object, and that's valid. But my overall concern is that while these methods literally do the same thing, the classes themselves are not particularly related, so introducing a common base hierarchy for a single (protected) method does not strike me as a suitable fit.

Here's my throwaway thought that I'm not even sure I like:

Define an empty interface that each class can "implement," then define an extension method against that interface.

```
internal interface IFaultThrower
{        
}

internal static class IFaultThrowerExtension
{
    internal static void ThrowIfNotNull(this IFaultThrower thrower, Fault fault)
    {
        if (fault != null)
        {
            throw new WhateverException(fault.reasonText);
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow the related classes to get rid of their own private methods and invoke this common one.

```
 // this.ThrowIfContainsFault(response);
 this.ThrowIfNotNull(response.Fault);
```

Again, not sure I like it, but I'm also not sure I like the same general idea creeping into multiple classes, either.

Comment: Does AlphaResponse, BravoResponse etc all inherit the same interface or class or abstract class?

Comment: No, I've morphed the names of these service objects into something readable for presentation purposes, but they have no common ancestor (not counting `object`). An example of a real name might be something like `EckBarBrusselsproutResponse_Type94` (seriously).

Comment: Is it possible to inherit from an `IResponse`? It would greatly simplify a lot of work.

Comment: @IAbstract - It's possible, I suppose, to use a partial class definition for each of the response objects. I just had another thought of perhaps adding an extension method directly for the `Fault` object and forgetting a fake inheritance approach entirely.

Comment: Which web service platform is this? ASMX, WCF, or other?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, other. C# client, but Java service.

Comment: "Add Service Reference" or "Add Web Reference"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Service Reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bad idea to introduce an empty interface to just add an extension method to it. You should think about an interface as a contract and not merely a way to introduce syntax sugar :)

I believe instead of playing with extension methods it is enough to introduce a separate, helper, internal class whose only purpose would be to throw an exception if fault object is null:

```
    internal class FaultResponseChecker
    {
        internal static void ThrowIfNotNull(Fault fault)
        {
            if (fault != null)
            {
                throw new WhateverException(fault.reasonText);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you, as I, don't like static methods, then you can use IoC container to inject  IFaultResponseChecker into the constructor of every class.

Comment: This is practically line for line how I left it yesterday, except it's an extension method (`this Fault fault`).

Comment: As an update, we are presently doing a rearch of the project, and I am indeed electing to use composition instead of inheritance and also instead of a static method. Not using anything like an IoC container, although it does expose the fault handling dependency via the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If AlphaResponse, BravoResponse etc all inherit an interface "IResponse" then you could do this.

```
internal static class FaultThrowerExtension
{
    internal static void ThrowIfContainsFault<T>(this T response) where T : IResponse
    {
        if (response.Fault != null) throw new WhateverException(fault.reasonText);
    }
}
```

Update : 
After reading your comment that they don't have a common Interface you could then do this.
This is a lot more messey though.

```
internal static class FaultThrowerExtension
{
    internal static void ThrowIfContainsFault<T>(this T response) where T : class
    {
        var type = typeof(T).FullName;

        foreach (var propertyInfo in PropertyInfoCache[type])
        {
            if (propertyInfo.Name == "Fault")
            {
                var fault = propertyInfo.GetValue(value, null);
                if (response.Fault != null) throw new WhateverException(fault.reasonText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```